# String to do a command?

Tags: c#

Why doesn't this work?
I should be able to type: `print test` and it should `Console.WriteLine("test")`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _command = Console.ReadLine();
            _do(_command);
        }
    }

    private static void _do(string whatdo)
    {
        string[] prams = whatdo.Split(' ');
        if (prams[1] == "print")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prams[2]);
        }
    }
```

I don't see why this doesn't work.

Comment: Array indexes start at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that you are new arrays. Array indexes start at *0*, not *1*. I know this is hard to understand for a beginner but you just have to live with it.

In other words, if you enter "print test", params[1] would return "test" so your code is wrong. And when you execute params[2], an `IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrown.

Here is how to fix it:

```
private static void _do(string whatdo)
{
    string[] prams = whatdo.Split(' ');
    if (prams[0] == "print")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prams[1]);
    }
}
```

See the change?